# XPATH, return specific elements within specific div

Tags: xpath

From this particular div below, I am trying to grab the available sizes, which is the "value" property here:

```
<input id="swatch-0-s-6072559239" type="radio" name="option-0" value="S" class="">
```

So I need to return: XS, S, M, L, XL

I have been trying variations of this:

```
//div[@class='swatch_options']following-sibling::input@value
```

But this is not working.

```
<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="0"> <div class="option_title">Size</div> <input id="swatch-0-xs-6072559239" type="radio" name="option-0" value="XS" checked="" class=""> <div data-value="XS" class="swatch-element xs-swatch"> <label for="swatch-0-xs-6072559239">
            XS <span class="crossed-out"></span></label></div> <input id="swatch-0-s-6072559239" type="radio" name="option-0" value="S" class=""> <div data-value="S" class="swatch-element s-swatch available"> <label for="swatch-0-s-6072559239">
            S <span class="crossed-out"></span></label></div> <input id="swatch-0-m-6072559239" type="radio" name="option-0" value="M" class=""> <div data-value="M" class="swatch-element m-swatch available"> <label for="swatch-0-m-6072559239">
            M <span class="crossed-out"></span></label></div> <input id="swatch-0-l-6072559239" type="radio" name="option-0" value="L" class=""> <div data-value="L" class="swatch-element l-swatch available"> <label for="swatch-0-l-6072559239">
            L <span class="crossed-out"></span></label></div> <input id="swatch-0-xl-6072559239" type="radio" name="option-0" value="XL" class=""> <div data-value="XL" class="swatch-element xl-swatch available"> <label for="swatch-0-xl-6072559239">
            XL <span class="crossed-out"></span></label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath syntax for following sibling and input@value are wrong,

try below

```
//div[@class='swatch clearfix']/input[@name='option-0']
```

Also, your parent div tag is not closed.

Check the output here

https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp?editors=1010